# What are two possible values for AC in the circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

Two radii of two concentric circles are $15$ and $7$. $AB$ is a diameter of the larger circle  that intersects the smaller circle at $C$ and $D$. Find the two possible values for $AC$. (the questions has no image)

I think one is $8$. I can't figure out the other one.

Comment: When you choose C and D, C can be closer to A or closer to B. If C is closer to A, the answer is 8, but if C e closer to B the answer is 22.

Comment: Start by drawing a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the position of C/D like the comments said, it can be $15-7=8$ or $15+7=22$[image: Here is the picture btw]Here is the picture btw.